# Syscall in Golang to dll lib

Tags: go, goland, panic

I can't bring the string to MZFanDll.dll in Goland and call func inside dll.

```
func main() {
    user32 := syscall.MustLoadDLL("MZFanDll.dll")
    messageBox := user32.MustFindProc("GET_OP_CALCULATION")
    text, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString("ECF(K)6E192-PLHDAJ1;0;1.2;0;20;200;500")
    MB_OK := 0
    ret, _, _ := messageBox.Call(
        uintptr(0),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(text)),
        uintptr(MB_OK))
    fmt.Printf("Returned: %d\n", ret)
}
```

When I run this code I'am getting panic

```
panic: Failed to load MZFanDll.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Whats wrong? How to avoid the panic?

Comment: try replacing the MZFanDll.dll file with a new copy from a reputable source. Alo check the path while calling MZFanDll.dll in your code.